# ACCESS Database query

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am trying to recieve values between specific dates. But my code gives error

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM gider WHERE [tarih] Between #" + startdate + "# and #" + enddate+ "#";
```

and I am getting following error

> An exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Syntax error in date in query expression '[tarih] Between #22.03.2006 15:31:48# and #22.03.2016 15:31:48'.

I searched a lot but all code examples look like mine. I couldn't find a solution.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Don't know the specific access syntax. But apart from that: your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://www.bobby-tables.com)!

Comment: Unfortunately Guy, tried both. Also thanks Rene, i ll fix sql inj risk after i find the problem

Answer (score 3):

You should use `OleDbParameter` in your query. It will fix 2 problems at once.

1. It will take care of converting the date into the correct format for the query
2. It will prevent SQL Injection.

Example:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM gider WHERE [tarih] Between @startdate and @enddate";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@startdate", OleDbType.Date).Value = startdate;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@enddate", OleDbType.Date).Value = enddate;
```

Comment: Thanks, I did like this but now i get Additional information: "Data type mismatch in criteria expression." error. My definitions in c# DateTime startdate, DateTime enddate and in access: Date/Time General Date

Comment: Maybe if you specify the `SqlDbType`. Change to: `cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@startdate", SqlDbType.Date) { Value = startdate});`

Comment: This answer is definitely on the right track, but (1) you don't need to use the `new` construct when adding parameters, and (2) the exception shows that the code is using OleDb so the answer should use OleDb... objects instead of Sql... objects.

Comment: Good point about using OleDb objects. I updated my answer. And I'm not sure about the `new` maybe you can give an example ? I didn't see a function that allows to specify the name, DbType and value at the same time.

Comment: cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Date).Value = startdate;

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
1:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM gider WHERE [tarih] Between '" + startdate + "' and '" + enddate+ "'";
```

2. try to format your date as `yyyy-mm-dd`